# When applying for a higher education job, do I need to list my bachelors?

Tags: cv, job, degree

If I did a bachelors a long time ago in an unrelated field and I am applying for a job that requires a PhD And a Master's should I put the bachelor's degree? Is it necessary?

Comment: In my experience on hiring committees at a community college, the fact that a person has a graduate degree does not guarantee even minimal competence in the subject at the freshman level. Graduate programs vary greatly in quality. Some will take any warm body. For this reason, we take the undergraduate degree very seriously, and we require a transcript and look carefully at undergraduate grades. Even people with a PhD from a well-known university will sometime demonstrate a shocking lack of competence in an interview when asked freshman-level questions.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  An academic CV should list every academic degree that you have earned.

If you don't list it, it will look as though you got a PhD without ever getting a bachelor's degree at all, which would be very strange and perhaps suspicious.

Comment: +1. Consider what the team reviewing your application would think if they didn't see a bachelor's degree...at the very best it would not negatively affect their decision (unlikely), while at the worst it makes it look like you have something to hide and severely impacts their decision (likely)

Comment: There are countries that didnt previously award bachelor's degrees. Most of my co workers have a Masters degree then doctoral degree but no bachelor's degree.

Answer (score 3):

You not only should put in the bachelor's degree, in most cases you **must** do so. Many schools consider falsifying or submitting an incomplete record a form of fraud, and consider that sufficient grounds to terminate employment if it's discovered after the hiring process is complete.

The only exception I can think of is in situations where the information asked for specifically includes a statement such as "please list only your most recent degree" or something to that effect.

Comment: Thanks! If the committee is interested however would they not just request it? At this point my Bachelor's is not relevant and to get transcripts would be a nightmare. If I have two Master' s and a PhD in the field will they ask for bachelor's transcripts too??

Comment: In many cases, yes. They may ask for all of your transcripts, regardless of level.